# When I publish a VB .NET application will references be included?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a VB .NET application that calls a couple of SQL .NET objects, and as such I had to add references to the proper .DLL's to get these to be populated correctly.

This works fine on my local machine where all the .DLLs reside in known areas (and after I added the reference they `import` correctly). My question is that once I build or "publish" the app, will the .DLL's be included or should I figure out some other way of making sure these DLLs are included?

This will be the first app I've created that actually uses external references, so I'm not sure what options I have to do this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to develop this, and was planning on just handing out the compiled .EXE but if it won't include the DLLs I guess I would need an installer?

Comment: How are you publishing it?

Comment: I made an edit that hopefully clarifies it a little. To be honest, this is new to me so I don't know how I'll publish it. In the past it's been enough to hand out the compiled .EXE, but this is the first time I've needed additional references.

Comment: @SeanLong you need all the references with your exe. And yes you need installer.

Comment: OK. Simple question, simple answer. I'll start reading about that.

Comment: You may combine multiple DLL's inside your .EXE file if you wish. There is a tool available from NuGet called [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge) that will allow you to do this (it will make your .EXE larger of course, and the libraries will not be accessible externally). You can Google for a tutorial on how to do this - its fairly basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're publishing using the `Publish Wizard` it's very easy to check what will be included during the deploy and also what is needed to run your application.

1. Go in your `Project Properties --> Publish`
2. Check `Application Files` and `Prerequisites`
3. Under Application Files you can select what's to be included (if it's not already!)

[image]