# Export data from VB to Excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

On VS 2012 I have created a VB.NET calculation application (outputs based on variable inputs), i need to save these input & output data to certain cells in excel sheet, 
here is a sample of the code i use:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open("D:\bookl.xlsx")
        xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

        xlsWorkBook.Close()
        xls.Quit()

End Sub
```

my problem here is that in every time i click the save button it saves the data to a excel sheet file which i have to specify its path previously.

What i wish to do is if there is any way to load from VB it self then choose where to save it (because iam going to use it in a lot of machines, so i don't want to put the excel file in the same path each time i use the application in any other machine)

Comment: What happens if you use xls.Workbooks.Add instead of xls.Workbooks.Open("filename")? I think this should create an untitled workbook and Excel will then show a save dialogue when you try to close it. Is that what you want to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Open Excel file from My.Resources location**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim resourcesFolder = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\Resources\")
    Dim fileName = "book1.xlsx"

    xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open(resourcesFolder & fileName)
    xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

    xlsWorkBook.Close()
    xls.Quit()

    MsgBox("file saved to " & resourcesFolder)
End Sub
```

The resource template xlsx file must be copied to the output directory, so edit its properties and choose (actually I'm not super sure you need this...)

```
Build Action = Content
Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always
```

**P.S. this is just a sample to use with your current code, but I strongly suggest using [EPPlus Library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) if you want to create/save/modify excel files.**

Comment: smart solution, thanks for it, but the question here, can i generate the predefined excel file from VB it self, meaning to load the excel sheet to VB resources, then the output excel sheet will contain the data and saved, without needing to choose the excel file then open it to save the data on it. thanks for your time & sorry iam little bit beginner here

Comment: thanks alot, it is working finally, really appreciate your help, but a small problem happened when i try to build the program, because the file location is wrong, literally it says         "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): 'C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\95O0CANR.V0V\Resources\book1.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted."

Comment: is this happening during build or publish?

Comment: I added that file using the Resources tab, simply "add existing file" and I can build without any problem. Are you sure the file is still there, with the same name?

Comment: yeah i added it using "add existing file" & it runs successfully,the problem happens when i publish it.

Comment: @user3151946 have you tried changing those settings like I wrote : Build Action and Copy To Output directory? in the file properties. Have you checked in the publish options if your file is getting exported? Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905773/1225646

Comment: okay now i tried alot, the conclusion is: there is no problem with the pdf file link i created in the same form, the problem is only with the excel file, i added the 2 files (pdf&excel) to the project resources as you told me & i adjusted the build path, but the thing i noticed is that at the build folder there is no resources folder & the book1.xlsx is on the root of the build folder, so i tried to adjust the code, but it didn't work too, so don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: @user3151946 I'm doing what I can... is your book1 inside the folder like this? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3997430/temp/Capture.PNG

Comment: I don't see your Resources folder. try to create it manually like in my photo OR change the path and remove "resources\" from the path string

Comment: i added it, but again this is the updated solution explorer & error message:   http://goo.gl/d0dS5w

Comment: @user3151946 try DELETING that file from the solution, then right click on folder "add existing item", add again and check every option from the beginning. properties and publish. it must be a really stupid thing....

Comment: didn't work too, it works only when i do stupid thing, copying the resources folder to the desktop, so iam really stuck here, so please here is a link for it try it & tell me:    http://goo.gl/5R50sT

Comment: @user3151946 I can't try that here now (no vs 2012), open a new question meanwhile and ask

Comment: thanks thanks thanks alot for your support, i fixed it finally, but ofcourse with your help. simply i replaced the resources folder path level to be like [ Dim resourcesFolder = IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\Resources\") ] & i added [ xls.Workbooks.Add() ] before close, so the entered new data don't replace its predecesor, again thanks in advance for your time & your patience

Comment: @user3151946 np, glad you solved, welcome to SO and thanks for accepting. ps: now you can also vote up, you have 15 points ;) good luck

Comment: thanks alot @Vland for everything, it's all by your guided support